# What is the recommended way to add Jackson mixin annotations dynamically?

Tags: jackson

I am using Jackson 2.3 in a JAX-RS application deployed (currently) to GlassFish 4.1.

I would like to be relieved of the burden of having to know of all the mixin classes ahead of time that might show up in my application as it matures.  I'd like for my `ObjectMapper` to be able to discover them as things roll along.

I've written a `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>` that, in its `getContext(Class)` method, does some configuration lookup to figure out what a mixin class might be for a given target class (following some naming conventions).  If it finds such a class, then it loads it and adds it to the `ObjectMapper` using `addMixInAnnotations()`.

It occurs to me that this on-demand discovery of mixin annotations probably doesn't work well with a shared instance of an `ObjectMapper` (perhaps changing configuration at this stage in the game is too late, or perhaps there are thread issues) and that there must be a better way.  What is it?